# Проект не подключается к PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

Я написал datasourse файл и поместил его в deployment-каталог сервера WildFly туда же поместил JDBC драйвер

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <datasourses schemaLocation="https://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasourses_1_1.xsd">
        <datasourse jndi-name="java:jboss/exampleDS" pool-name="PostgresSQLPool">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql-42.2.8.jar</driver>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <pool>
            <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>postgres</user-name>
            <password>postgres</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        </validation>
        </datasourse>
    </datasourses>
```

затем в папке META-INF создал файл persistence.xml который ссылается на datasourse файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="examplePU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/exampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Далее создал класс с сущностями которые по идее должны были создаться в таблице БД

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Ошибка

> 19:49:01,027 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ds.xml".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "example-ds.xml"

Проблема в том что сервер не стартует с первого раза , и таблицы в БД не создаются , подскажите в чем проблема ?

Comment: какая ошибка при старте? PS. зачем вы откатываете форматирование?

Comment: Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ds.xml".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "example-ds.xml"        Форматирование откатил потому что подразумевало удаление описания файла persistence.xml , посчитал это важным

Comment: стоп вы про форматирование <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>  это ??)))))

Comment: нет, я именно про форматирование вопроса, сделал чтобы было читабельно. Не могли бы добавить описание ошибки в вопрос? Это важная информация, и у нас проблема в файле example-ds.xml, а не в настройках хибернейта.

Comment: Прошу прощения было 2 предложения правки , ваше не сразу заметил , уже подтвердил , спасибо большое                                              
19:49:01,027 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ds.xml".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "example-ds.xml"

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас у вас проблема парсинга example-ds.xml

Comment: спасибо , а как исправить?